# Intellij: Before commit: run git hooks

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to be enable "run git hooks" before commit, I know its possible since i enabled it once (in one project, depicted below)

but i cant remember / figure out how to do this in another project

can you please help?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back then i couldn't find it, but later on i did, so just wanted to share it with you guys.

The following package will do it for you [pre-commit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit)

**Its amazingly simple, just install it:**

```
npm install pre-commit --save-dev
```

**and add this to your package.json**

```
{
  "pre-commit": ["test", "build"],
}
```

and you're golden

Answer (score 9):

[Quote from IJ forums:](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001808439-Before-commit-run-git-hooks)

> The option appears there when git hooks that can be skipped -
> pre-commit and commit-msg - are added to the repo.
>
> So you need to create hooks in .git/hooks to make it appear.

Comment: And the file must be executable (`chmod +x`)

Comment: And you need to restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the settings section from the question you can find it at **View > Tool Windows > Commit** and then if you click the gear above the commit comment text input you will see the menu.