# IntelliJ: don't run git hooks

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I tell IntelliJ IDEA not to run the git pre-commit hooks for a commit? I seem to recall there being a "Run Git Hooks" checkbox that could be disabled, but it no longer appears to exist in my commit dialog:

[image: screenshot of git options in commit dialog]

[Previous questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607355/intellij-before-commit-run-git-hooks) seem to agree that there used to be this "Run Git Hooks" option, and I recall it myself, but as you can see it's not present anymore. Can I get it back, or is there some other way to skip the git hooks? I don't see anything relevant in the settings dialogs.

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Does your hook have an executable bit? Does the hook run if you run commit via cmd.exe?

Comment: I just noticed this today too. I'm using Husky, are you? I wondered if it's a Husky-specific issue.

Comment: Yeah it's also Husky for me. That's pretty suspicious.

Comment: I think this is because Husky v7 doesn't use .git/hooks anymore, but a .husky in your project; I think IntelliJ was using this /hooks folder to determine if there were. I think this is because husky v7 uses git new core.hooksPath

Comment: I opened an issue here : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51693